# EF 4.1 One to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have what I consider a very simple data model and I'm struggling badly with EF 4.1 CF.

My data model has two classes:

```
public class Site {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Building> buildings { get; set; }
}

public class Building {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public int siteId { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

My configuration files are like this:

```
public class SiteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Site> {

public SiteConfiguration() {
  HasMany(c => c.buildings)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.siteId);
  }
}
```

In my controller for MVC I simply want to remove a building from a site.  Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, int siteId) {
  var site = repo.GetById(siteId);
  var building = site.buildings.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
  ou.buildings.Remove(site);
  repo.Save(); 
}
```

My Error Message:

> The operation failed: The relationship
>   could not be changed because one or
>   more of the foreign-key properties is
>   non-nullable. When a change is made to
>   a relationship, the related
>   foreign-key property is set to a null
>   value. If the foreign-key does not
>   support null values, a new
>   relationship must be defined, the
>   foreign-key property must be assigned
>   another non-null value, or the
>   unrelated object must be deleted. Any
>   thoughts or suggestions would be
>   greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you expand your code example to include the definitions of `repo` and `ou`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Building 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SiteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Site> 
{
    public SiteConfiguration() 
    {
        HasMany(c => c.buildings);
    }
}

public BuildingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Building> 
{
    public BuildingConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(s=>s.Site);
    }
}
```

This tells the site that it can have many buildings, and tells the building that it REQUIRES a site, and doesn't make sites worry about building requirements or vice versa.

As I understand it, you only pull in HasMany.WithMany/WithRequired in many-many relationships and the like.

Comment: Why does the building have to know about the site?  I really don't want that relationship to exist as I will never need to navigate from building to site, it will always be site to building.\

Comment: Interesting - I suppose it doesn't - but then you would just have "HasMany" in the site config w/o the HasRequired (which tried to tie buildings back to sites).

Answer (score 0):

You could try and replace this line:

```
public int siteId { get; set; }
```

With this:

```
public Site site { get; set; }
```

There are two ways to describe a relationship with the class names or with the id. You combined both that is why you got the relationship already exists.

Comment: By doing all this I've gotten a different error now.  A relationship from the 'Site_Buildings' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Site_Buildings_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.